# How to call a function inside a cursor in pl/sql?

Tags: plsql

I have declared a function which is returning some string as

```
function(varchar2) return varchar2;
```

I want this function to be called from inside of a cursor like

```
open p-cursor for select * from employee where emp_name = function(ssn).
```

But it throws some error.

The query being used in cursor is working fine when executed separately.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Answer (score 1):

When you say you have "declared" a function do you mean like this?

```
declare
  function f (p varchar2) return varchar2
  is
  begin
    ...
  end;
begin
  open p_cursor for select * from employee where emp_name = function(ssn);
  ...
end;
```

You can't use a function like that in SQL.  You would have to create the function in the database so that it can be used outside the PL/SQL program - for example:

```
  create or replace function f (p varchar2) return varchar2
  is
  begin
    ...
  end;
```

Or if you are creating a package then you can make the packaged function public like this:

```
  create or replace package pkg is
    function f (p varchar2) return varchar2;
    ...
  end;
```

Then it can be used in other code like this:

```
  open p_cursor for select * from employee where emp_name = pkg.f(ssn);
```

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks for your interest in my query.
I have created the function inside a package and trying to use this function in a procedure in the same package. The procedure contains a cursor from which I want to use this function but it throws some error. But when I execute the query used in the cursor it gives me right result.
I just want to know a way to call a function inside a cursor query.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you cannot use a group function in a where clause. But this function(ssn) being not a group function cannot also be used here.

You can use it as a sub query, serves the purpose.

open p-cursor for select * from employee where emp_name = (select package_name.function_name(ssn) from dual);